# Calculating XOR of the two images

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I came across the following function to calculate the XOR of 2 images. Could someone please explain to me what is actually happening here? Also, how is it different from the inbuilt function with Pillow [logical_xor](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.logical_xor)?

```
 from PIL import Image, ImageChops

 def get_xor(image_1, image_2):

    i1 = ImageChops.invert(image_1)
    i2 = ImageChops.invert(image_2)

    return ImageChops.invert(ImageChops.add(ImageChops.subtract(i2, i1), ImageChops.subtract(i1, i2)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Pillow logical XOR

> Logical XOR between two images. At least one of the **images must have
>   mode “1”**.

Comment: Any benefit for not using the inbuilt method with Pillow?

Comment: The built-in Pilliw function is used if they work with the bitonal image.

Comment: Could you please answer the question "Could someone please explain what is actually happening here?", and also tell us how this is any different.